# Anchor tag scroll to div not working for #section

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm unsure why but randomly on my wordpress site, #section tag on  stopped working across whole site? Not sure where to look, been looking at it for a while can can't figure it out

Where should I start looking?

I'm using http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/page-scroll-to-id/demo/demo.html plugin - This was working totally fine.

Comment: any console warnings and or errors?

Comment: Only error in console is related to video background for vc row : Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin

Other than that, XHR finished loading: GET when I click FIRST and it does something completely different like tawk.to mp3 which is completely irrelevant. Any click after that does nothing

Comment: confirming the plugin script and its dependencies (jQuery) are loaded?

Comment: Can we have a chat room to discuss?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by removing plugin completely and adding scroll-behavior: smooth to html CSS. Plugin wasn't working properly